# Chrome extension crash with "Could not execute Chrome hidden method: dispatchOnLoad"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My extension always crashes when I close Chrome.

Log:

```
....

[4686:519:0510/175611:VERBOSE1:page_load_histograms.cc(878)] PLT: 4609ms http://www.weibo.com/miser?wvr=5&
[4107:28931:0510/175611:VERBOSE1:resource_loader.cc(466)] CancelRequestInternal: http://12.76.web1.im.weibo.com/im?jsonp=parent.org.cometd.script._callback56&message=%5B%7B%22channel%22%3A%22%2Fmeta%2Fconnect%22%2C%22connectionType%22%3A%22callback-polling%22%2C%22id%22%3A41%2C%22clientId%22%3A%225y9a81a060p8zawjgc1bpjrk175uecs%22%7D%5D&1368179766308
[4686:519:0510/175611:VERBOSE1:chrome_v8_context.cc(126)] Could not execute chrome hidden method: dispatchOnUnload 
[4686:519:0510/175611:VERBOSE1:dispatcher.cc(873)] Num tracked contexts: 33
[4107:28931:0510/175611:VERBOSE1:resource_loader.cc(336)] OnResponseStarted:http://12.76.web1.im.weibo.com/im?jsonp=parent.org.cometd.script._callback56&message=%5B%7B%22channel%22%3A%22%2Fmeta%2Fconnect%22%2C%22connectionType%22%3A%22callback-polling%22%2C%22id%22%3A41%2C%22clientId%22%3A%225y9a81a060p8zawjgc1bpjrk175uecs%22%7D%5D&1368179766308

.....
```

Who knows the reason？

Comment: What does your extension do? Can you show us the relevant extension code? If you can make a small test case that reliably reproduces this behavior, it would probably be suitable for [filing as a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).

Comment: Possibly related: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-extensions/7ZIr3wv0lco